# Grails War dont work on my Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, grails

i have a Tomcat 7 - Server on my debian machine.
Grails Version 2.2.4
Mysql - Server

1 Application runs fine, but my second i create with grails doesnt work.

i load it with the manager up -> try to start:

```
FAIL - Application at context path /Ligaportal-Thomas-0.3 could not be started
```

The catalina:

```
tail -f /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.                                     java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor                                     .java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Oct 25, 2013 2:34:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Oct 25, 2013 2:34:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Oct 25, 2013 2:34:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Ligaportal-Thomas-0.3] startup failed due to previous errors
startup failed due to previous errors
**strong text**
```

How can i fix it?

thx thomas

Comment: "due to previous errors" can you provide more content of catalina.out?

Comment: this is all what i get from my catalina.out

this is my command
tail -f /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out

Comment: `tail` returns only the last lines of your file. Open it with a text editor and you will see that it have more info.